# 403 forbidden error at Nginx

Tags: nginx, centos

I'm running Nginx on CentOS 6 and I'm always getting 403 Forbidden every time I try to access to my site...

My config file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    location / {
      root /home/mysite/www;
      index index.html;
    }
}
```

And this is what I found in error.log

```
[error] 16853#0: *29 open() "/home/mysite/www/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /test.html HTTP/1.1", host: "mysite.com"
```

I also run "ls -l" to these directories thinking it's about a chmod problem... this is what I got:

ls -l /usr/share/nginx/html (Working)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3652 Apr 26 20:36 index.html
```

ls -l /home/mysite/www (Not working)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysite mysite 3652 Apr 26 20:36 index.html
```

---------------------------------------- EDIT

ls -ld /home/mysite/www

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysite mysite 4096 Jul 20 20:52 /home/mysite/www
```

ls -ld /home/mysite

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysite mysite 4096 Jul 20 20:52 www
```

ls -ld /home

```
drwx------ 4 mysite mysite 4096 Jul 20 18:39 mysite
```

Comment: Please show us the result of `ls -ld /home/mysite/www`. And `ls -ld /home/mysite` and `ls -ld /home`.

Comment: ls -ld /home/mysite/www

drwxr-xr-x 2 mysite mysite 4096 Jul 20 20:52 /home/mysite/www


ls -ld /home/mysite

drwxr-xr-x 2 mysite mysite 4096 Jul 20 20:52 www


ls -ld /home

drwx------ 4 mysite mysite 4096 Jul 20 18:39 mysite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated:

```
ls -ld /home
drwx------ 4 mysite mysite 4096 Jul 20 18:39 mysite
```

If nginx is running as an ordinary user, presumably as something other than "mysite", then it cannot access /home as only the `mysite` and `root` users have this permission.

To find out what user nginx is running as type:

```
ps faxu
```

.. and search for the nginx process.
    To  get  the  nginx  user  just  do

> ps  faxu  | grep  nginx